# TYPO3: Add some default constraints to repository

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am looking for a way to add default constraints to a TYPO3 (extbase) repository. I found already the following solution, but this just partly working for me:
https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/205096/

With the above solution it is still possible to get an entry in the show view, which looks like this in the controller:

```
public function showAction(\Vendor\Myext\Domain\Model\User $user)
{
    $this->view->assign('user', $user);
}
```

Is there maybe a way to add more options in "enablecolumns" of the TCA? Or are there other solutions ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an entity to an action, it does not use your entity Repo at all.

Extbase uses so called TypeConverters, to resolve any data you pass to an action. When you pass an entity/object (via __identity property) the converter performs an own query.

If you want to change the behavior here, you can simply provide your own TypeConverter and register it with a higher priority, than the default PersistentObjectConverter.

I did an extension which does this to provide session based entities. You can see there how to build and register an own converter.

https://bitbucket.org/t--3/extbase_session_entities/src